# Creating a bootable Arch USB key, not appearing bootable

Tags: arch-linux, boot, live-usb, usb-device

### Question

Hello all!

Please pardon the fact that this is probably a very simple problem with a simple answer. I'm having some difficulty booting into a USB key I bootstrapped and configured Arch onto. I am using a 128GB Samsung Fit 3.1 USB-A key, in case it matters.

Synopsis: I used Etcher to write the (shasum-checked) Arch ISO onto a random USB key. I booted into the LiveUSB and plugged in my Samsung 3.1 key. I properly formatted the USB key for GPT/UEFI booting. I bootstrapped Arch onto the key, configured it, installed GRUB2 into the ESP, configured GRUB2, and blessed it from MacOS. When I reboot, my Arch USB key does not appear in the bar. My Mac happily booted up the Arch LiveUSB I made, plus many more distros' LiveUSBs I made, proving that it is configured to allow USB booting. So, why cannot I not see my Arch system, what am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

### Full Log

If you would like a more specific log of what I did to get to these steps, here they are in full:

#### Download the ISO

Download ISO from mirror or torrent it using the links provided by https://www.archlinux.org/download.

Check shasum using `$ openssl sha1 path/to/arch.iso`
Use Etcher to write that to the USB key
Restart your computer and boot into the installer (LiveUSB)

#### Format the USB key's partitions

`# fdisk -l`
    in this example, we assume our USB key is called `sdd`

```
# parted /dev/sdd
. mktable gpt
. mkpart primary fat32 1MiB 261MiB
. set 1 esp on
. mkpart primary ext4 261MiB 100%
. name 1 ‘the-efi-partition’
. name 2 ‘archenemy-beta’
. quit
```

`# parted /dev/sdd print`
All good here.

`# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdd2`

`# mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdd1`

#### Configure the internet

Plug in an ethernet cable
`# ping archlinux.org`.
All looking good.

#### Boostrap Arch

`# mount /dev/sdd2 /mnt`

`# mkdir /mnt/efi`

`# mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/efi`

`# vi /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`
Mess with the order to prioritise some geographically closer mirrors.

`# pacstrap /mnt base base-devel`

#### Configure Arch

`# genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab`

`# arch-chroot /mnt`

`[]# ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime`

`[]# hwclock --systohc`

`[]# vi /etc/locale.gen`

`[]# locale-gen`

`[]# locale -a`
All good here.

`[]# echo “LANG=en_US.UTF-8” > /etc/locale.conf`

`[]# echo “KEYMAP=us” > /etc/vconsole.conf`

`[]# echo “archenemy-beta” > /etc/hostname`

`[]# vi /etc/hosts`
    write the following:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost
127.0.1.1   archenemy-beta.localdomain      archenemy-beta
```

`[]# passwd`

#### Install & Configure GRUB2

`[]# pacman -S grub efibootmgr`

`[]# mkdir /boot/grub`

`[]# grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/efi --bootloader-id=GRUB`

`[]# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

`[]# exit`

`# umount -R /mnt`

#### Bless the EFI Partition

Boot into MacOS

`$ diskutil list`
    for this example we will assume it as `disk2`

`$ mkdir ~/efi`

`$ sudo mount -w -t msdos /dev/disk2s1 ~/efi`

`$ bless --folder ~/efi/EFI/GRUB --file ~/efi/EFI/GRUB/grubx64.efi`

`$ diskutil eject disk2`

`$ rm -rf ~/efi`

Answer (score 1):

I realised what the problem was... I hadn't seen the page [for USB installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key#Installation) so I hadn't done some important steps...

In `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` move the `block` and `keyboard` hooks before the `autodetect` hook and re-create the initial ramdisk with `mkinitcpio -p linux`.

When installing GRUB, i forgot to add `--removable` which I think was the really important step. Sorry for wasting your time!